# Vertical text in table with booktabs

Tags: tables, multirow, booktabs

I managed to create a table with booktabs package with this code :

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|lll}
\toprule
          & Surveillance de                     & Fonctionnalité & Feedback \\
\midrule
Verre     & Indépendance lors d'AVQs            &                &          \\
\midrule
Osselet   & Dextérité                           &                &          \\
Cube      & Préhension globale de la main       &                &          \\
\midrule
Bracelet  & Activité motrice du bras            &                &          \\
Pull-over & Extension du coude                  &                &          \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Récapitulatif des fonctionnalités de chaque objet}
\label{recap_fonctionnalites}
\end{table}
```

Which gives this result : 
[image]

I would like to add vertical text for each big row between the `midrule` like this :

[image]

How can I do that plz ?

Thanks you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by combining `multirow` from the eponymous package with `rotatebox` from the `graphicx` package as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\toprule
    &      & Surveillance de                     & Fonctionnalité & Feedback \\
\midrule
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{AVQ} &Verre     & Indépendance lors d'AVQs            &                &          \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Main}} &Osselet   & Dextérité                           &                &          \\
&Cube      & Préhension globale de la main       &                &          \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Bras}} &Bracelet  & Activité motrice du bras            &                &          \\
&Pull-over & Extension du coude                  &                &          \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Récapitulatif des fonctionnalités de chaque objet}
\label{recap_fonctionnalites}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that I have additionally removed the vertical line as `booktabs` horizontal rules are not intended to be used in combination with vertical lines.

Answer (score 1):

I propose this variant, with `intersecting` horizontal  and a (`thicker`) vertical rules,  an adjustment of the position of the vertical text, and some padding of rows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\aboverulesep=0pt
\belowrulesep=0pt
\setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{ll!{\color{Gainsboro!60!Lavender}\vrule width0.4em}lll}
\toprule
    & & Surveillance de & Fonctionnalité & Feedback \\
\arrayrulecolor{Gainsboro!60!Lavender}\midrule[0.1em]
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{AVQ} &Verre & Indépendance lors d'AVQs & & \\
\midrule
\multirowcell{2}[-0.4ex]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Main}} &Osselet & Dextérité & & \\
&Cube & Préhension globale de la main & & \\
\midrule
\multirowcell{2}[-0.3ex]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Bras}} &Bracelet & Activité motrice du bras & & \\
&Pull-over & Extension du coude & & \\
\arrayrulecolor{black}\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Récapitulatif des fonctionnalités de chaque objet}
\label{recap_fonctionnalites}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]